# Python invalid value encountered in log10

Tags: python

This block for calculating Q_train_ref is giving me the log10 error

**RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10**

```
 Q_train_ref = 20 * np.log10(np.sqrt(2) * special.erfcinv(2 * BER_train_ref))
Epoch now 0 SR now 25.655268675901986
Q_train Sim now -31.973141549095576 Q_train Sim ref now nan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/f/freiredp/anaconda3/envs/MScProject/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/freiredp/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/221.5591.52/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/home/freiredp/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/221.5591.52/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/users/f/freiredp/MScProject/multitask.py", line 115, in <module>
    result = ch.full_line_model(channel, wdm)
  File "/home/freiredp/MScProject/channel_model.py", line 949, in full_line_model
    nl_shift_x = nonlinear_shift(points_x, points_orig_x)
  File "/home/freiredp/MScProject/channel_model.py", line 891, in nonlinear_shift
    return np.dot(np.transpose(np.conjugate(points_orig)), points_orig) / np.dot(np.transpose(np.conjugate(points_orig)), points)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in dot
ValueError: shapes (262144,) and (229376,) not aligned: 262144 (dim 0) != 229376 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Means you pass 0 or a negative number into the log

Comment: Please post a minimal working example, we have got no idea, what you are doing.